# Error from chokidar after angular 10 upgrade

Tags: angular, angular10

we recently upgraded from Angular 8 to Angular 10 and everything seems working fine but there is,
one error that keep appearing on the command line console when any action happens on the app.

```
PS C:\Users\m333\UIWorkspace\cc-apps-res> ng serve

chunk {app-admin-study-setup-study-setup-module} app-admin-study-setup-study-setup-module.js, app-admin-study-setup-study-setup-module.js.map (app-admin-study-setup-study-setup-module) 2.73 MB  [rendered] 
chunk {app-admin-study-validation-study-validation-module} app-admin-study-validation-study-validation-module.js, app-admin-study-validation-study-validation-module.js.map (app-admin-study-validation-study-validation-module) 81.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {app-patient-registration-patient-registration-module} app-patient-registration-patient-registration-module.js, app-patient-registration-patient-registration-module.js.map (app-patient-registration-patient-registration-module) 1010 kB  [rendered]
chunk {default~app-admin-forms-forms-setup-module~app-admin-study-setup-study-setup-module} default~app-admin-forms-forms-setup-module~app-admin-study-setup-study-setup-module.js, default~app-admin-forms-forms-setup-module~app-admin-study-setup-study-setup-module.js.map (default~app-admin-forms-forms-setup-module~app-admin-study-setup-study-setup-module) 423 kB  [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 3.97 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 427 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {quill} quill.js, quill.js.map (quill) 427 kB  [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 9.44 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 1.16 MB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.34 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 5.8 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-12-29T14:43:58.758Z - Hash: 101217fef6a3b8132311 - Time: 84209ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys
```

'

I have no idea what chokidar is. This is the first time am hearing about.

any Idea on how to fix this?
Help Appreciated!!

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936085/error-from-chokidar-c-error-ebusy-resource-busy-or-locked-lstat-c-dump

Comment: i didn't find my solution yet. i see there are some decrepated empty rxjs operator so i replaced with the current operator and that didnt resolve my issue

Comment: please post entire log...

Comment: @Posto updated with full log

Comment: @Posto any other idea, how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Please re-check your imports...

Comment: @Posto I checked all my imports and i dont see any wrong imports