# how do I fix a library add error in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli, vuex-modules, vuelidate

I have a problem installing the Vuelidate vue library in an existing project and in the two commands `npm install --save vuelidate` or `npm i vuelidate` and this error would someone ask me to help please? I already imported it in the main.js, I just need to solve this problem

```
Chokidar error (C: \ node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or blocked, lstat 'C: \ DumpStack.log.tmp'
Chokidar error (C: \ node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or blocked, lstat 'C: \ DumpStack.log.tmp'
Chokidar error (C: \ node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or blocked, lstat 'C: \ hiberfil.sys'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, it states: `resource busy or blocked`, so you basically have your server running or alike. Try killing everything that could run on the background (your app, related services, middlewares) and run your npm command again.

Comment: 1. There is an actual vue3 branch for `vuelidate`: https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/tree/next#install-via-plugin-in-vue-30 2. the **original poster** _Lucas Menezes_ (not me so !), never talked about vue3 (and it's not in his tags). 3. a `resource busy or blocked` is not really related to his current version of Vue. 4. if you disagree with my opinion, feel free to post **your own answer**, but still: I don't see why you're telling me all of this in comments...

Comment: So even closing all the service doors still with this same problem, I don't know if it could be that but I didn't find the vuelidate in the package-lock.json dependencies nor do I know how to add it, but this error still appears: (

This dependency was not found:

* .vuelidate in ./src/main.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save .vuelidate
Error from chokidar (C: \): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C: \ DumpStack.log.tmp'

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the content of your `package.json` please ? :) Also, this answer should be tried on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61936086/8816585