# Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or > locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

Every time when i run or restart my backend server, it shows following error in my terminal:

> **Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or
> locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'** Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules):
> Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or
> locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'      Error from chokidar
> (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat
> 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

My tech stack is: Nodejs, MongoDb, Mongoose, React, NPM, Material-ui
If you still want to add me any code or file, let me know

Its pretty annoying, How can i eliminate this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/1037

Comment: @ZdravkoPernikov no it doesn't answer my question. It would be better if someone elaborate on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error from chokidar (C:\‌): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936085/error-from-chokidar-c-error-ebusy-resource-busy-or-locked-lstat-c-dump)

Comment: @SinanYaman its for Angular and totally strange solutions are there, I'm asking for MERN stack specifically Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Try this to solve your problem:
1- Delete node_modules folder.
2-run npm install .
3-run npm cache clean .

Comment: It solved when i restarted my server but then when i came after restarting whole system i.e. my laptop, it shows same errors again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me after installing JSON-SERVER globally and watching the server. I'm not sure if that was the cause but it happened right after the watching started.

I aborted the watch and the app wouldn't load with npm run serve.

I tried everything suggested by every forum post I could find including deleting node_modules folder and package.json, npm install, cache clean, cache clean --force, resetting my computer, disabling anti-virus and I have no malware software installed.

The only thing that finally worked was creating a whole new project and copying and pasting the files from the old corrupt one into a new one.  I also had to run npm install again so all the dependencies could be installed.

I don't understand why JSON Server should have anything to do with the cause unless the watching locks folders and renders the app unrunnable.

I will try again after I make a few copies of my app to experiment on because copying and pasting files is not a fun job unless your project is small enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

Just run this command in (Ubuntu/Debian). It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue using `chokidar.watch(['/src/...'])` I had accidentally added a leading slash to one of my paths. Removed and not getting the error any more.