# @material-ui icons react not resolved on windows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to import material ui  into my react code although i encoutered an error saying

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/Search' in 'C:\Users\Dominik\code\facebook\src'
```

Shall I put a path to material ui or in package.json somewhere in VSCode ? There is version of material-ui in package.json so I dont know why i encouter such error.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you install the package `npm install @material-ui/icons`.
This is how you import your Material UI Icon component to react
`import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';` and you render it like `<SearchIcon/>`

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArTg3PgWw2jtf-eife8-P4ftMp8?e=tdTbZ5 I do as you say and still encoutering an error saying                                                                                            
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/Search' in 'C:\Users\Dominik\code\facebook\src'
Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61936086/1930155 This might help

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CR10jyRz This is package.json @Aravind Reddy

Comment: Can you install this package and try once npm i @material-ui/icons

Comment: Done. Works. But was installed before.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to linux and it finds the module but there's an error: https://snipboard.io/Pz1YEH.jpg

My code

```
`import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import AccessAlarmIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    
    <AccessAlarmIcon></AccessAlarmIcon>  <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`