# strange issue in react regarding dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-hooks

I have many react dependencies in my `package.json` including react-select `"react-select": "^5.2.1",`
as of now appliction is running properly. I have to create serchable dropdown so when I write below line in my react component.

```
import select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
```

then I get below error.

```
Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

I also deleted `node_modules` and did `npm install` still it is not working. actually it is happening if any dependency I install. I have react version   `"react": "^17.0.2",`

how to resolve that?

Comment: Have you checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936085/error-from-chokidar-c-error-ebusy-resource-busy-or-locked-lstat-c-dump

Comment: Yes. I deleted nod_modules and did npm install after going to this answer