# Vaadin.. Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

Tags: javascript, vaadin

i get the following error message when i start my vaadin-app

```
2022-07-16 14:46:19.276  INFO 14076 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Started Webpack. Time: 17866ms
2022-07-16 14:46:19.426  INFO 14076 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : Issues checking in progress...
2022-07-16 14:46:20.173  INFO 14076 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

```
@Route("")
@JsModule("./register.js")
public class RegisterView extends VerticalLayout { ........ }
```

does anyone know what this is ?

best regards

Comment: have you tried: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/web-components#integrating-a-js-module-into-vaadin

Comment: I just tried this ` @NpmPackage(value = "@iota/identity-wasm", version = "0.6")
@JsModule("@iota/identity-wasm/node/identity_wasm.js")`. and that still does not work

Comment: What is `C:\DumpStack.log.tmp`? Does windows nowadays single-lock files?
Do you have multiple processes running, that hang on to this file?

Comment: no actually only one process

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?  I know that Windows 10 is finicky about things writing to the root of C:, or deleting, moving, etc.

Comment: I use Windows 11 :-(

Answer (score 1):

here the answer this question :)

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dumpstacklog-file/eba04d25-bac2-4173-b9d5-b1a8fc47f64e

DumpStack.log.tmp is a hidden file on Windows.
and with the following steps you could you unlock the file :

1. Open the Registry Editor.
2. Navigate to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", "SYSTEM", "CurrentControlSet",
   "Control", and finally "CrashControl"
3. Once you've opened the "CrashControl" key, look at the values pane
   to the right and look for "EnableLogFile". If it doesn't exist,
   create it. Its type must be "DWORD".
4. Set its value to 0.
5. Exit the Registry Editor.
6. restart your computer

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936085/error-from-chokidar-c-error-ebusy-resource-busy-or-locked-lstat-c-dump)

The problem may actually come down to automatically added imports